# first_or_create: determining which is called

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I call first_or_create like so:

```
collection = Collection.first_or_create(:title => title)
```

Is there a way to determine if the result is an existing entry or a freshly created one? So far the best solution I've come up with is to use first_or_initialize:

```
collection = Collection.first_or_initialize(:title => title)
if collection.id.nil?
  <process>
  collection.save
end
```

But this feels a bit hacky. Is there a way to get this information directly from first_or_create?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `first_or_create` you can't know for sure is it a newly created object or one from the database. Possible tricky solution is to compare `created_at` value with current time. This works if you don't create objects often.

Btw, why you need to know is it the newly created object or not?

Comment: After the object is created, I need to manipulate other objects in the database. Typically, I'd do this with an after_create callback, but in this case, I'm pulling params from a form that (as far as I know) can't be passed to after_create.

Answer (score 23):

`first_or_create` takes a block that'll only be executed if a new record is created, you can set some flag inside that block to indicate it's a new record, for example

```
MyObject.where(attr: "value").first_or_create do |obj|
  @my_object_created = true
end
```

Answer (score 20):

As far as I know you can't know.  Two options are to check the `created_at` time (unreliable), or instead use `first_or_initialize`, then check to see if `new_record?` is true, and if so, do your other operations and then call `save!`.  This may be the best approach for you anyway, since you may very well not want to finalize the save until the other relations are saved, and you probably want to do all of that in the same database transaction.